# I'm trying to create user specific access to my todolist website with Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, command-line-interface

I'm getting an error after I make migrations in the command line. Please help

When I try to create a new todo list I get this error:

```
AttributeError at /create/
'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'todolist'
```

-views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import ToDoList, Item
from .forms import CreateNewList
# Create your views here.

def index(response, id):
    ls = ToDoList.objects.get(id=id)

    if ls in response.user.todolist.all():

        if response.method == "POST":
            if response.POST.get("save"):
                for item in ls.item_set.all():
                    if response.POST.get("c" + str(item.id)) == "clicked":
                        item.complete = True
                    else:
                        item.complete = False

                    item.save()

            elif response.POST.get("newItem"):
                txt = response.POST.get("new")

                if len(txt) > 2:
                    ls.item_set.create(text=txt, complete=False)
                else:
                    print("invalid")


        return render(response, "main/list.html", {"ls":ls})
    
    return render(response, "main/home.html", {})

def home(response):
    return render(response, "main/home.html", {})

def create(response):
    if response.method == "POST":
        form = CreateNewList(response.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            n = form.cleaned_data["name"]
            t = ToDoList(name=n)
            t.save()
            response.user.todolist.add(t)

        return HttpResponseRedirect("/%i" %t.id)

    else:   
        form = CreateNewList()

    return render(response, "main/create.html", {"form":form})

def view(response):
    return render(response, "main/view.html", {})
```

-models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class ToDoList(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="todolist", null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Item(models.Model):
    todolist = models.ForeignKey(ToDoList, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    complete = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

I used this command:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

I used the tutorial from TechWithTim(link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sm1mokevMWk&t=7589s) to do this project. It works fine for him but not for me.

Someone, please tell me where I went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Request is passed to views. response is what is returned from views, not the other way around(although can name request in different ways, but it's better to do it meaningfully).

```
def create(request):
```

ForeignKey creates a one-to-many relationship. The model in which this field is declared is considered secondary, and the model that is declared in this field is considered primary. Description [here:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey)

By using the primary model(ToDoList), you can get the data associated with it from the secondary model(Item). To do this, a special property (object) with the name **secondary model_set** is created in the primary model by default. In our case: **item_set**.

**Note that the property is in lower case(the property is created with a small letter).** You can also define it on your own using related_name (in this case, it will be the way you write it, without the _set prefix).

In the view, I first get data from the primary model based on the secondary(aaa.todolist that is, referring to the field of the secondary model, I get the name of the primary model, since the primary class returns the name. And then I get user through the name).

Then I use the primary to get the data of the secondary model (in the secondary model, I took only the first value). All received data is displayed on the page.

```
def create(request):
    aaa = Item.objects.get(id=1)
    name = aaa.todolist
    user = aaa.todolist.user

    bbb = ToDoList.objects.get(id=1)
    fff = bbb.item_set.all()[0]#takes the first element from the QuerySet .
    print(bbb.item_set.all())


    return HttpResponse(f"""
        <p>ferst name: {name}</p>
        <p>ferst user: {user}</p>
        <p>second todolist: {fff.todolist}</p>
        <p>second text: {fff.text}</p>
        <p>second complete: {fff.complete}</p>
    """)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [ 
    path("create/", create, name="create"),
]
```